# Setting jQuery offset through variable

Tags: jquery, css, offset

I am Trying to place a div through jquery ,The code below works if I put constant values of top and left into : $(divToAdd).offset({ left:TableX[i]  , top:TableY[i]})  ;
instead of the array , I have also tried to alert() the values of TableX[i] which is working .

```
var divToAdd ;
        var TableX=[] ;
        var TableY=[] ;
    var TableX = <?php echo json_encode($TableX);?> ;
            var TableY=<?php echo json_encode($TableY);?> ;
            for(i = 1 ; i <= <?php echo $num ;?>; i++)
            {divToAdd = $("<div></div>");
            $(divToAdd).addClass('dragged1');
            $(divToAdd).offset({ left:TableX[i]  , top:TableY[i]})  ;
            $('#frame').append(divToAdd);
            }

included this php file :

    <?php 
        include('connect.php') ;
        $cnt_table;
        $TableX = []; 
        $TableY =[];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TableX , TableY FROM layout ");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $num=$num_rows;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

                $TableX[$num_rows] = $row['TableX'] ;
            $TableY[$num_rows] = $row['TableY'];
        //echo $TableX[$num_rows]."\n" ;
        //echo $TableY[$num_rows]."\n";
        $num_rows--;

        } 
    ?>
```

Enlightened people , Guide me through this ...

Comment: Please post the actual code that browser sees. We can't mentally process your php into unknown array.

Comment: Have updated it , please see . The problem is with Table[i] , it's not considering the fetched value .

Comment: That isn't the javascript source code from browser. Browsers don't run php. Also your array is only going to have length of 1 since you overwrite the same index every iteration of your loop

Comment: That's the only code required to create a div . I have pasted the complete javascript . Can you tell me which part is overwriting ?

Comment: $num_rows-- is there at the end , and I have echoed the value to check , secondly all the different values are getting stored in database as well , So the issue seems to be in javascript .

Comment: @Maurice Perry ..The above code is working ?

Comment: Well, not exactly the same code: I don't have a database, but I have just filled the two php arrays with constants. The javascript part is identical. BTW: is your javascript code in a php file or a separate .js file?

Comment: My javascript is in .php file . 
The code works if I put constant value instead of TableX[i] , Secondly The code creates div but does not consider the offset .It creates all the divs in same position .

Answer (score 0):

```
I have found a solution , Although still did not understand what is wrong with offset() .
The new code is : 

var divToAdd ;
        var TableX=[] ;
        var TableY=[] ; 
        var TableX = <?php echo json_encode($TableX);?> ;
        var TableY=<?php echo json_encode($TableY);?> ;
        for(i = 1 ; i <= <?php echo $num ;?>; i++)
        {
            //alert(TableX[i]);
        divToAdd = $("<div></div>");
        $(divToAdd).css('top' , + TableY[i] );
        $(divToAdd).css('left' , +TableX[i] );
        $(divToAdd).addClass('dragged1');
        $(divToAdd).attr("id","table"+i);
        //$(divToAdd).offset( {left:TableX[i]  , top: TableY[i]} );
        $('#frame').append(divToAdd);
        }
```

The added lines are :

```
$(divToAdd).css('top' , + TableY[i] );
$(divToAdd).css('left' , +TableX[i] );
```

Thanks to the people who responded ...